# converting long date to date time format for my specified date

Tags: java

I have a long value of 20140811. I mean to say that its my present date.
I need to convert this date into 2014-08-11 13:14:07.672 something like this.
But I got the result as 1969-12-31 23:35:40.811.

I used the following code,

```
long date = 20140811
Date d = new Date(date);
System.out.println(d);
```

Kindly , help me out guys

Comment: Do you have a very good reason to store your date in this format? If you control the input, change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DateFormat to parse the value:

```
long  l=20140811;

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
df.parse(String.valueOf(l));
```

Comment: I didnt copy the answer,just you were faster.And look our local variables are same too.Lol :)

Comment: But i am getting Fri Jan 16 19:02:02 CST 1970
I didnt get my desired output

Comment: @Karthikeyan Do you take the code exactly from the answer?

Comment: @Jens To be brief I am working on restful services, my third party API is returning date in long format. I am following CST time. My target is to convert the long date (20140811) to today datetime format with minutes, second and milliseconds then store it in database.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `DateFormat` solves the issue of parsing .

For a precise list of conventions,please see this link [DateFormat Letter conventions](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm)

```
long date = 20140811;
String s = String.valueOf(date);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS");//throws ParseException
Date d = df.parse(s);
```